# Element-wise quotient of two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, database

How can I combine the columns returned by two `SELECT` statements to give their element-wise quotient?

Query 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table1
WHERE col2 = 1 AND col3 > 5
GROUP BY col4
ORDER BY col4
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table1
WHERE col2 = 1
GROUP BY col4
ORDER BY col4
```

So if they return something like:

```
Query 1        Query 2
count           count
-----------------------
1              5
2              4
```

I will get:

```
quotient
-------
0.2
0.5
```

Comment: What if they return different numbers of records?  Indeed, Query 1 will probably return fewer records than Query 2 due to its more restrictive filter criteria.  Also, since neither query applies an ordering, how should records from the two resultsets be matched?

Comment: Hold on; you would get either 1 or NULL, wouldn't you, depending on whether the row has a col3 value greater than 5.  If it does, the result is 1 (because col1 / col1 = 1), and if it does not, then you are dividing by NULL.  Can you clarify your question with complete (3-column) example data and an explanation of which bits are joined with which other bits?

Comment: are tables sharing a column on which they can be joined? this is a very vague question for someone with your rep points...

Comment: @pOcHa: There appears to be only one table.

Comment: @eggyal: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. Yes they will have the same number of records.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Haha good catch. I simplified the queries a bit too much and now the question trivial. It has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the 4-column version of the question, we can assume that the quotient is between groups with the same value in `col4`.  So, the answer becomes:

```
SELECT col4, SUM(CASE WHEN col3 > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS quotient
  FROM table1
 WHERE col2 = 1
 GROUP BY col4;
```

I've retained `col4` in the output because I don't think the ratios (quotients) will be useful without something to identify which quotient is associated with which values, though theoretically, the answer doesn't want that column in the output.

Comment: (Almost) perfect, Thanks! Just had to make sure it wasn't an integer division and it worked.

Comment: If it was an integer division as written, then you'd simply need to cast one (or both) aggregates to a FLOAT and then you'd be home and dry.

Answer (score 1):

In case your actual queries cannot be simplified as per the other answers, you can join the subqueries, like this:

```
select j1.count / j2.count as quotient
from (
   SELECT col4, COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM table1
   WHERE col2 = 1 AND col3 > 5
   GROUP BY col4      
) j1
join (
   SELECT col4, COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM table1
   WHERE col2 = 1
   GROUP BY col4
) j2 on j1.col4=j2.col4
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't need two separate queries at all:

```
SELECT   SUM(col3 > 5) / COUNT(*)
FROM     table1
WHERE    col2 = 1
GROUP BY col4
ORDER BY col4
```

Comment: I understand the logic here but I got a syntax error: `Incorrect syntax near '>'`